# found : Unit required: List[Int] type mismatch error for for loop

Tags: scala

type mismatch error found   : Unit required: List[Int], for for loop in scal how to resolve ?

i am writing this function and it is giving me error for the first for loop.

```
def f(num:Int,arr:List[Int]):List[Int] = {
     for (i <- arr){
         for (j <- 0 until num){
             var tmplst = List[Int]()
             i :: tmplst
         }
     }
 }
```

i was expecting that for each element of array the next for loop will run.

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite the for comprehension  as follows:

```
def f(num:Int,arr:List[Int]):List[Int] = 
    for {
       i <- arr
       j <- 0 until num
    } yield i
```

Comment: where should i put the list and addition of element to  List ?

Comment: @rupeshkumar Why would you do this? The for-comprehension results in a `List` consisting of all `j` values so you dont have to reassign a new copy of the List on each iteration by yourself and return it in the end.

Comment: From OP's original code, I think the for-comprehension should yield `i` instead of `j`.

Comment: Nice Function , Thanks for the Help, can share Link to get more on For Comprehension.

Comment: @rupeshkumar You can read a detailed explanation at the official documentation page https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/yield.html . In particular, it is explained what the `yeild` keyword means.

Comment: @Some Name how can i view the elements in each iteration of the function  you wrote ?

Comment: @rupeshkumar What do you mean view the elements? If you want to filter some elements out than simply add `i <- arr; if cond` as specified in the _Example 3_ of the link I provided above.

Comment: I mean the values of each parameter which which are passed to foldLeft and the values which are getting appended to list, Just to understand the flow more clearly.

Comment: @rupeshkumar There is no foldLeft generated after expanding the for comprehension. It acts as `flatMap` - `flatMap` - `map`

Answer (score 2):

Your function need to return `List[Int]` which is not happening.
Since you are using mutable variable increase the scope of it and return it something like below:

```
def f(num: Int, arr: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
  var tmplst = List[Int]()

  for (i <- arr) {
    for (j <- 0 until num) {
      tmplst = i :: tmplst
    }
  }

  tmplst
}

println(f(5, List(1, 2))) // List(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
```

**If you want to make it functional,**

```
def fFunctional(num: Int, arr: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
  arr.foldLeft(List.empty[Int]) { case (list, i) =>
    (0 until num).foldLeft(list) { case (l, j) =>  i :: l }
  }
}

println(fFunctional(5, List(1, 2)))
```